# How Nest thermostat communicates

Tags: node.js, heroku, raspberry-pi

I want to build a Raspberry Pi (RPi) based device similar to the Nest Thermostat, except that I want to control light switches. I know I could easily code up a Node.js script on the RPi and then just hook it up to my local router and control it with a PC hooked up to the same router.

But, I want to make it more like a Nest. I want to be able to control 20 (or more) RPis across different subnets through a cloud provider like Heroku.

The Nest thermostat does not require the user to open a port on their router so that the Nest server can communicate with it.

How is Nest able to control customer's thermostats over the web without enabling port forwarding in the customer's router?

Comment: Since you have to set up an account with their cloud service, I wouldn't be surprised if the Nest unit is polling that service via a simple HTTP API. I have no insight into this though, purely speculation.

Comment: HTTP polling makes the most sense, as it is unlikely to be blocked by firewalls along the way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blog post [Nest Thermostat API using Node JS and Nest API Update](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1754) discusses the API 
between the thermostat and the nest lab servers. In particular:

> The API uses mostly JSON formatted data POSTed to their web servers.

So there is your answer. By periodically POSTing data to the nest web servers using HTTPS, Nest is able to avoid having the user open any ports on their router.

---

For what it's worth, the unofficial API (in node.js!) from the blog post is available on github: [Unofficial Nest API on Node](https://github.com/wiredprairie/unofficial_nodejs_nest).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. How do you think Nest manages the thermostats connections? Do you think that each one has a serial number? And that that serial number is associated with a user account on their server? And that a Nest thermostat is periodically POSTing data to the Nest server along with it's serial number. So then when a user logs on to the website and issues a command, the Nest server knows which Nest thermostat to issue the command to?

Comment: No problem. Yes, it looks like each user account is associated with one or more thermostat serial numbers. I'm not quite sure how the polling works but presumably the thermostat would submit a serial number so that only data for that one stat would need to be sent. And the serial number is definitely used when issuing a command from the web interface, since in the API example `SERIALNUM1` is used to change the thermostat's current set point.

Comment: Here's what I think may be going on: Nest thermostats constantly connect to a Nest server through a web socket and POST their device ID. When a user creates a new account, their account is associated with the thermostat by typing a code in that is presented to them on the thermostat during the initial configuration. Now when a user wants to send a command to their thermostat, Nest loops through their list of active Nest thermostat connections, finds the one with the corresponding device ID, and sends the command to it using the active socket connection. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds about right, although a web socket is not necessarily required. The thermostat could just check periodically to see if there is a change request (such as a new set point). A web socket is faster and more efficient though. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with these devices to know exactly how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the thermostat periodically posts a request with the thermostat serial number to nest.  It may have timeouts in the http headers set to infinity or more likely, the nest server simply closes the connection after a minute or so if no command for that device has come in. Whenever nest closes the connection the thermostat opens a new one. When a command request comes in with serial number, its a quick lookup to find the thread currently connected to that thermostat. The command is sent in the payload of the current thermostat request, which is executed, the connection is closed, and the thermostat opens a new request to nest .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at eventSource in the HTML 5 standard. It does everything that is required.